# SQL Server issues when getting records starting from a date onwards

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to obtain all records starting from a date (included) onwards.

I get different records if I use below in where clause:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE DateTimeField >= '20101201'
```

than if I use below:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE DateTimeField >= Convert(datetime, '2010-12-01')
```

Why don't I get the same number of registers?

I use SQL Server 2008.

Comment: Let me guess... The datatype of the column `DateTimeField ` is either `varchar` or `nvarchar`? Also, if you run `SELECT Convert(datetime, '2010-12-01');` what is the resulting value?

Comment: Post a reproducible example. BTW `YYYY-MM-DD` is *not* a culture-invariant format. It's affected by the DATEFORMAT setting. What does `MONTH( Convert(datetime, '2010-12-01'))` return? Use either the unseparated `YYYYMMDD` format or the full ISO8601 format

Comment: Data type of the column and sample data needed, or else no one can possibly answer this.

Answer (score 3):

Your literal constant in the second case is language dependent, here is an example:

```
set language [British English]
SELECT Convert(datetime, '2010-12-01');
----
-- 2010-01-12 00:00:00.000

set language us_english
SELECT Convert(datetime, '2010-12-01');
----
-- 2010-12-01 00:00:00.000
```

While `'20121201'` is language independent.

So I suppose your session language (defined by your `login language` unless changed explicitely) is different from `us_english` and to fix the issue you should use language independent date literals `'yyyymmdd'`

Comment: Exactly.  "Which country are you in?" is an appropriate question to the OP.